# Floating point square root algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, floating-point, computer-science

I am wondering if anybody can provide me with some examples of floating point square root algorithms which can utilize a hardware divider.

Extra details:
I have a floating point unit I am developing which has a hardware floating-point IEEE-754 32-bit multiplier, adder, and divider. I already implemented square root using the Newton-Raphson method using only multiplication and addition/subtraction, but now I want to compare the throughput of square root if I have a hardware divider available to me.

1 particular input that is difficult to compute accurately is the square root of 0x7F7FFFFF (3.4028234663852886E38).

Comment: Straight-up Newton's method for finding sqrt(r) is `s <- (s + r/s)/2`.  You'll need to be a little careful about rounding to get it right.

Comment: @tmyklebu, that method requires a proper initial guess and also I believe you wrote the formula incorrectly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Square_root_of_a_number

Comment: @Lior Kogan: the article you linked is so flawed it does more damage than it informs. Wikpedia has a great page dedicated to square root algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution provide by @tmyklebu certainly appears to meet your requirements.

```
r = input value
s(0) = initial estimate of sqrt(r).  Example: r with its exponent halved.
s(n) = sqrt(r)
```

s <- (s + r/s)/2

It has quadratic convergence, performs the requested divide.  N = 3 or 4 should do it for 32 bit float.

[Edit N = 2 for 32 bit float, N = 3 (maybe 4) for double]

---

[Edit per OP request]
[Edit Added comments per OP request]

```
// Initial estimate
static double S0(double R) {
  double OneOverRoot2 = 0.70710678118654752440084436210485;
  double Root2        = 1.4142135623730950488016887242097;
  int Expo;
  // Break R into mantissa and exponent parts.
  double Mantissa = frexp(R, &Expo);
  int j;
  printf("S0 %le %d %le\n", Mantissa, Expo, frexp(sqrt(R), &j));
  // If exponent is odd ...
  if (Expo & 1) {
    // Pretend the mantissa [0.5 ... 1.0) is multiplied by 2 as Expo is odd, 
    //   so it now has the value [1.0 ... 2.0)
    // Estimate the sqrt(mantissa) as [1.0 ... sqrt(2))
    // IOW: linearly map (0.5 ... 1.0) to (1.0 ... sqrt(2))
    Mantissa = (Root2 - 1.0)/(1.0 - 0.5)*(Mantissa - 0.5) + 1.0;
  }
  else {
    // The mantissa is in range [0.5 ... 1.0)
    // Estimate the sqrt(mantissa) as [1/sqrt(2) ... 1.0)
    // IOW: linearly map (0.5 ... 1.0) to (1/sqrt(2) ... 1.0)
    Mantissa = (1.0 - OneOverRoot2)/(1.0 - 0.5)*(Mantissa - 0.5) + OneOverRoot2;
  }
  // Form initial estimate by using the above mantissa estimate and exponent/2
  return ldexp(Mantissa, Expo/2);
}

// S = (S + R/S)/2 method
double Sqrt(double R) {
  double S = S0(R);
  int i = 5;  // May be reduced to 3 or 4 for double and 2 for float
  do {
    printf("S  %u %le %le\n", 5-i, S, (S-sqrt(R))/sqrt(R));
    S = (S + R/S)/2;
  } while (--i);
  return S;
}

void STest(double x) {
  printf("T  %le %le %le\n", x, Sqrt(x), sqrt(x));
}

int main(void) {
  STest(612000000000.0);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Converges after 3 iterations for double.

S0 5.566108e-01 40 7.460635e-01
S  0 7.762279e+05 -7.767318e-03
S  1 7.823281e+05 3.040175e-05
S  2 7.823043e+05 4.621193e-10
S  3 7.823043e+05 0.000000e+00
S  4 7.823043e+05 0.000000e+00
T  6.120000e+11 7.823043e+05 7.823043e+05

Comment: Is there a better way for a starting guess for s(0). Also, with infinite iterations there appears to still be a large error

Comment: Large error issue: The error after each step is about the square of the previous.  e.g. 1% -> 0.01% -> 0.000001% etc.  If you are not seeing this I'd suggest a coding issue.  Maybe try the algorithm in another venue (e.g. Excel) first.  I'll edit the post to discuss initial estimate

Comment: My usage of `s <- (s + r/s)/2` converge rapidly for 612000000000. (3 iterations - see post.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to type that out.  How do you measure the error? Can you always guarantee full ieee-754 32-bit precision for a certain number of iterations?

Comment: error = (funtion_output - ideal)/ideal.  Yes, full (or full - 1) precision can be guaranteed after a few iterations.  The last precision bit or 2 is sensitive to how you encode s <- (s + r/s)/2.  Bad cases are near x = 1, 0.707 and 2.  I'll need to think on where _worst_ is.  GTG

Comment: My posted code uses `double`.  Using `float`, 2 iterations are needed with careful coding.

Comment: thank you, would you mind explaining what this part is for: if (Expo & 1) {
    // map (0.5 ... 1.0) to (1.0 ... 2/sqrt(2))
    Mantissa = (TwoOverRoot2 - 1.0)/(1.0 - 0.5)*(Mantissa - 0.5) + 1.0;
  }
  else {
    // map (0.5 ... 1.0) to (1/sqrt(2) ... 1.0)
    Mantissa = (1.0 - OneOverRoot2)/(1.0 - 0.5)*(Mantissa - 0.5) + OneOverRoot2;
  }
  return ldexp(Mantissa, Expo>>1);

Comment: Thank you chux, what are the reasons for having two different methods for the first estimate?  Is there a reference somewhere for this method as well?  MUCH THANKS!

Comment: The initial estimate is a simple linear approximation.  As odd exponents need to double the mantissa, might as well make an initial estimate for numbers with even/odd exponents different (and thus better).  A better estimate saves 1 iteration.  See wiki Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Comment: But the absolute error is not less than 2^-23.  That isn't considered full accuracy though right? I say that because in MATLAB I don't get as low of an error.

Comment: Hmm, I also don't have the convenience of frexp and ldexp on my platform I am coding for.  Is there any other way to perform these calculations without them but is still efficient?

Comment: Sounds like a good question to search or post: frexp and ldexp replacments?

Comment: I instead just converted the input to the 32-bit floating point value where I set the exponent equal to -1.  This acts as the mantissa. I also extracted the exponent. I did this all through masking. To get a final estimate for S, I set S = Mantissa*2^( (Expo-127) >> 1). In case anyone cares, in MATLAB pow2 and log2 can replace ldexp and frexp, respectively.  However, I didn't do that since for my platform I have to program in assembly.

Comment: Hi Chux, I just found that the square root cannot be compute properly with this algorithm for 0x7F7FFFFF , which equals 3.4028234663852886E38.  The square root for this input should be 0x5F7FFFFF, however, this algorithm gives 0x5F800000. This algorithm's answer answer:18446743523953737728.000000 Correct:18446743523953729536.000000.   Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: (Note: this is for using float, which I have to use since my application is 32-bit floating point and I am writing in assembly (not x86, but a special ISA).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33234/discussion-between-chux-and-starbox)